# Monotouch Unsubscribe From Events

Tags: c#, events, memory-management, xamarin.ios

I have been using Events instead of delegates in my MonoTouch project, typically using this pattern (iPhone app using Storyboards):

I call `PerformSegue` to present a new View Controller, and in `PrepareForSegue` method, I set the View Controller's properties and subscribe to its events using a lambda expression as such:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    if (segue.Identifier.Equals("NextViewControllerSegue")) {
        using (MyNextViewController destinationVC = segue.DestinationViewController as MyNextViewController) {  
            destinationVC.SomeProperty = "some value";
            destinationVC.Cancelled += (s, e) => {
                this.DismissViewController(false, null);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

(as an aside, I chain these Cancelled events where I need to close a hierarchy of View Controllers - whether this is good or bad is a question for another day)

My question is: I recently discovered that if you don't unsubscribe from an object's events, that object is not Garbage Collected. So I have changed the above code to:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    if (segue.Identifier.Equals("NextViewControllerSegue")) {
        using (MyNextViewController destinationVC = segue.DestinationViewController as MyNextViewController) {  
            destinationVC.SomeProperty = "some value";
            destinationVC.Cancelled += Cancel;
        }
    }
}

protected void Cancel (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as MyNextViewController).Cancelled -= Cancel;

    this.DismissViewController(false, null);
}
```

My question is this: is this pattern a good way to go about things? And will approach 2 (unsubscribing from the event in the event delegate) work? I am not sure where else to unsubscribe. Or should I move everything to use a notification pattern instead (as suggested here: [Should I prefer NSNotificactionCenter or .NET events when using Monotouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612448/should-i-prefer-nsnotificactioncenter-or-net-events-when-using-monotouch))?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, the event will cause the `destinationVC` to have a reference to `this`. Since `this` is most likely lower in the stack than `destinationVC` in a navigation controller, you don't really have an issue because `destinationVC` doesn't live as long as `this`.

Your second example isn't needed in your example, but it would be if:

- A controller subscribes to an event on an object that will be around for a long time, like a Model/ViewModel class
- A controller subscribes to an event on a previous controller in a navigation controller stack (same goes for modal controllers)